# How to close a SharePoint modal without refreshing the page?

Tags: 2013, javascript, development, asp.net

I am calling this method when the cancel button is clicked to close a form in SharePoint. When the modal is closed, it also refreshes the page. Is there any way to prevent the refresh through the code behind?

```
protected void closeModal()
{
     Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "return", "<script language='JavaScript'>window.frameElement.commonModalDialogClose();</script>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void closeModal()
{
     Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "return", "<script language='JavaScript'>window.frameElement.commonModalDialogClose(); return false;</script>");
}
```

add return false at the end should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
function openDialog(tUrl, tTitle) {
                 debugger;
                 var url = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;
                 url = url.replace(/\/$/, '') + '/';
                 tUrl = url + tUrl;
                 var options = {
                     url: tUrl,
                     title: tTitle,
                     width: 1200,
                     height: 535
                 };

                 SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);
     closeDialog();
   }
function closeDialog()
{
window.frameElement.commitPopup();
}
```